# After a gettext update be able to check if a translation file has been translated

Tags: poedit, gettext

I am looking for a program that tells me if my PO is already translated or not.

Basic question are:

- Is there any fuzzy,
- Is there any empty string.

The best would be to have this strings displayed so you can translate it and save them one after the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is navigate through untranslated string and fuzzy string.

If there is some, you should be able to modify them.

http://polib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#more-examples

**Edit**

Released : http://pypi.python.org/pypi/check_po/0.1